# Way to avoid non-null assertion while using useState in async Data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

Trying to use strict typescript with Next.js and React-query

There is problem that useQuery's return data is Post | undefined.
So I should make data given with useQuery not null with ! operator while allocating to useState

ESlint does not like non-null type assertion.
I know I could turn it off... But I want to do strict type check so I don't want to avoid this.

One way that I found was to use if statement to do null check
but React Hooks is not able to wrap it with if statement...

Is there any brilliant way to do it?

My code is like this

```
const Edit = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;

    const { data } = useQuery<Post>('postEdit', () => getPost(id as string));

    const [post, setPost] = useState<TitleAndDescription>({
        title: data!.title,
        content: data!.content,
    });
    const editMutation = usePostEditMutation();
    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <Wrapper>
                {data && <Editor post={post} setPost={setPost} />}
            </Wrapper>
        </MainLayout>
    );
};

export interface TitleAndDescription {
    title: string;
    content: Descendant[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
const [post, setPost] = useState<TitleAndDescription>({
    title: data?.title ?? '',
    content: data?.content ?? []
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-null assertion is for cases when you want to exclude null or undefined values from the type. For most cases you don't need it, you can cast to the type you want:

```
(data as Post).title
```

or provide a fallback value:

```
data?.title || ''
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can do:

```
const [post, setPost] = useState<TitleAndDescription>({
    title: data?.title ?? '',
    content: data?.content ?? []
});
```

as the current accepted answer suggests, it won't solve your problem as you will always have `undefined` in your local state, as it won't update automatically when new data comes in from useQuery.
data will be undefined on the first render because react-query needs to fetch it first. With useState, you are only passing in the initial value of the first render - which is undefined.

There is no need to copy data from react-query to local state. This just duplicates the single source of truth. You can just use the data returned from useQuery as it will always reflect the server value:

```
 const { data } = useQuery<Post>('postEdit', () => getPost(id as string));
const post = data ?? { title: '', content: [] }
```